# How to to register the time when the system outputs 1?

Tags: python

This code registers incoming data from serial USB port distance tracker and converts the data stream to `1` or `0` (if they pass a certain threshold) and adds a Unix timestamp

**Code:**

```
import serial
import datetime
import time

distance = 5

# Open serial usb port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 115200, timeout=0.05)

# converts data to 1/0 
def convertData(data):
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    data = data.replace('$BM,','') 

    try:
        data = float(data)
        if data <= distance:
        data = 1
        else:
            data = 0
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return data


while True:
    data = ser.read(9999999)
    measureunix = float(time.time())
    specData = convertData(data)
    print ('Distance:', specData,'Timestamp(Unix):', measureunix)
```

**Output in terminal:**

```
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.521877
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.572295
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.626737
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.677538
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.73111
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.786401
Distance: 1 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.839391
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.889872
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.940595
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381131.991894
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381132.043311
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381132.097168
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381132.149091
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381132.200407
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381132.25372
Distance: 0 Timestamp(Unix): 1495381132.306592
```

**Problem:**

As for the next step- I'm not sure how to do this, but I want to setup a counter that starts counting when the output is (1), continues that until there are two successive(0), then stops counting and prints out the time spent counting `(time_of_last(1)-time_of_first(1))` divided by the number of `(1)`'s and waits until the next `(1)` and starts it again.

**Background:**

I'm am trying to build a system that uses distance tracking laser to measure speed of rotating disc (disc has holes with a set diameter). So the laser would register spinning and it would be possible to understand the angular velocity and angle of the rotating disc

Perhaps there is a better way to do any of this, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't test this with real data, of course, but the following approach seemed to work with simulated input. Basically what you're doing is parsing a data stream of 0's and 1's, and a [Finite-State-Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) seems like a good way to do it. The logic for one can be encapsulated entirely in a single class:

```
class FSM(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = self.state0

    def transition(self, value):
        self.state(value)

    def state0(self, value):
        if value == 1:
            self.start = time.time()
            self.count = 1
            self.state = self.state1

    def state1(self, value):
        if value == 0:  # first 0?
            self.state = self.state2
        if value == 1:
            self.count += 1

    def state2(self, value):
        if value == 0:  # second 0 in a row?
            elapsed = time.time() - self.start
            try:
                rate = self.count / elapsed
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                rate = float('NaN')
            print('rate {}'.format(rate))
            self.state = self.state0
        if value == 1:
            self.count += 1
            self.state = self.state1
```

Using it is easy—just call its `transition()` method with each data value:

```
fsm = FSM()
while True:
    data = ser.read(9999999)
    measureunix = float(time.time())
    specData = convertData(data)
    print('Distance:', specData, 'Timestamp(Unix):', measureunix)
    fsm.transition(specData)
```

Comment: Note you really don't need to do the `float(time.time())` because `time.time()` returns floating point values.

Comment: Brandon: You're welcome. Actually, after some additional testing, I don't think it was quite right and added a `self.state = self.state1` at the end of the `state2()` method. Also added an exception handler in case the calculated `elapsed` time is ever zero and causes a division error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can keep track of the states and value you are trying to track:

```
start_one_time = None
last_one_time = None
zeros_seen = 0
ones_seen = 0
while True:
    data = ser.read(9999999)
    measureunix = float(time.time())
    specData = convertData(data)
    print ('Distance:', specData, 'Timestamp(Unix):', measureunix)

    if specData == 1:
        zeros_seen = 0
        ones_seen += 1
        if start_one_time is None:
            start_one_time = measureunix
        last_one_time = measureunix
    else:
        zeros_seen += 1
        if start_one_time is not None and zeros_seen == 2:
            duration = last_one_time - start_one_time
            print (duration / ones_seen)
            start_one_time = None
            ones_seen = 0
```

**Note:** that I was not able to test this so it might contain some errors.